# Creating inventory of space available on a web page

Tags: html

I am working on a prototype to load content in specific placement/position on a web page. I will have a table with mapping of content and web page placement/position.

Questions:

1. How do we define a placement on a web page? By web part name, div id etc?
2. How do we divide a web page into multiple sections and assign placements/positions?
3. If i have to maintain a table to store placements/positions on a web page, what details should it contain?

Appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. usually you use div's. use the class atribute if the part occurs more than once. Use id's when the item occurs only once on the page like headers.
2. You can do this with CSS
3. Table's for layout is considered bad practice, use css colums. The data you will need, is the the position and the data itself at a minimum and any meta data you want to dispay, but this can be added later if its a relational table.

For example: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have used div Ids as the sections don't repeat.